# Define a LaTeX command that takes character as argument, instead of taking it in { }

Tags: macros, characters

I want to define a command that takes two of its arguments as the first **two** characters after; just like `\left(` and `right)` take the first character after them, even if they're braces `left\{` and `right\}`.

I want to create a command `\lr` that I defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\lr}[3]{\left#1 #2 \right#3}
```

And use it like `\lr{<}{stuff}{>}`.

But wanted to use it like `lr<>{stuff}`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. What's the context? What else does the command need to do? Are these the first two arguments? What might those characters be and what has to be done with them?

Comment: @cfr , sorry about that, added the example.

Comment: (Not a math person, so I'm sure this is kind of a stupid question, but) what else might be used besides `<>`? Are there only one or two other possibilities in your use case, or are there more like six or ten?

Comment: I could use `{}`, `()`, `<>`, `[]`, and all of those but changing one of the characters for a dot `.`, e.g. `{.`, `.]`.

Comment: You can't say `\left{`. At least, I can't. I have to say `\left\{` etc.

Comment: @cfr, you're right, I too have to use `\left\{`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the braces around an argument are omitted, it takes the argument as a single token.  Since delimiters are a single token, every works just fine if you just reverse the sense of the `#2` and `#3` from the OP's trial guess.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lr}[3]{\left#1 #3 \right#2}
\begin{document}
\[  \lr<>{stuff}        \]
\[  \lr[|{\frac{a}{b}}  \]
\[  \lr\{.{XYZ}         \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it behaves like that by default... Did not expect that, thanks.